# Delegate of UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am facing this problem I can't decide who should be delegate of UICollectionView which is subview of UITableViewCell. UITableView has its controller as delegate. But who should be delegate of UICollectionView inside each UITableViewCell? :) And if it is supposed to be controller, how do I recognize correct model that I should use pass the data into UICollectionView since I don't have UITableViewCell instance or NSIndexPath instances available.

Comment: Please, checkout this link. It will help you a lot. http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell  It also links to a github repo https://github.com/AshFurrow/AFTabledCollectionView

Comment: so basically I need to subclass UICollectionView to pass correct data to it with its native datasource protocol?

Comment: That's it. It adds an index to the collection view and then uses it to access the correct data from the model.

Comment: ok, if thats legit solution, will keep this open anyway

Comment: Resolved Link for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618501/3400991

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618501/3400991