# UICollectionView inside TableViewCell not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView contains one horizontal scroll UICollectionView in every cell like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ServiceTypeCell
    cell.collectionView.delegate = self
    cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.lblName.text = serviceTypes[indexPath.row].name
    cell.tag = getTag(indexPath)
    print("uitableviewcell : \(indexPath)")
    return cell
}
```

And in every UICollectionViews

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let cell = collectionView.superview?.superview as! ServiceTypeCell
    let indexPath = getIndexPath(cell.tag)
    print("uitableviewcell from uicollectionview : \(indexPath)")
    return serviceTypes[indexPath.row].services.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let tableViewCell = collectionView.superview?.superview as! ServiceTypeCell
    let tableViewIndexPath = getIndexPath(tableViewCell.tag)
    let service = serviceTypes[tableViewIndexPath.row].services[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ServiceTypeDetailCell
    cell.lblName.text = service.name
    return cell
}
```

My problem is UICollectionView Datasource only called between UITableViewCell index 0 to 3. Why does this happen?

My print debug result like this

```
uitableviewcell : [0, 0]
uitableviewcell from uicollectionview : [0, 0]
uitableviewcell : [0, 1]
uitableviewcell from uicollectionview : [0, 1]
uitableviewcell : [0, 2]
uitableviewcell from uicollectionview : [0, 2]
uitableviewcell : [0, 3]
uitableviewcell from uicollectionview : [0, 3]
uitableviewcell : [0, 4]
uitableviewcell : [0, 5]
uitableviewcell : [0, 6]
```

Comment: Did you set the scroll direction of UICollectionView as horizontal?

Comment: I think first stop the tableviewDidselect. Then select the collection view cell.

Comment: @Imad yes I already set horizontal scroll in storyboard

Comment: @PhaniRaghu What do you mean stop tableviewDidSelect? This tableview does not need any selection

Comment: Sry I misunderstand the question.

Comment: What is your `getTag` method doing. @MatYus

Comment: @iPeter it is my method to use indexpath as tag,combine section and row as one integer

Comment: Because `collectionViews` are being reused. How many cells are visible at once the same number of `collectionViews` are being created so delegates will be call for those only. What happens if write `cell.collectionView.reloadData()` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` just after `cell.collectionView.dataSource = self` line.?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure , whether this can **Resolve** your issue or not , but having consuming so much time finally i found the answer why **CollectionView delgate method not gets called** when it is embed inside **TableView** :

we basically use these two :

- UICollectionViewDataSource
- UICollectionViewDelegate

but forget to conform this : **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

After conforming this (UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout) did solve my issue .

Hope it will solve other issue too.
Feel free to comment and share your feedback.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your collection view instances are reused with cells.
Only 4 instances are being created and reused.

You can write your collectionview logic in your custom tableview cell and make custom cell as delegate and datasource of collectionview.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, its only happen in iPhone5. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: write collection view datasource and delegate methods in ServiceTypeCell cell and assign delegate and datasource as cell to collectionview. Also make a 'service' property in cell and assign data to cell in cellForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: I try move uicollectionview datasource into ServiceTypeCell class, still got same result. in my uitableviewcell cellForRowAtIndexpath:

cell.serviceType = serviceTypes[indexPath.row]
cell.collectionView.delegate = cell
cell.collectionView.dataSource = cell

Comment: the only solution i got is set cell.collectionView.reloadData() in cellForRowAtIndexpath but it will reset the position of cell to 0 again if i scroll top and back to this cell

Answer (score 0):

Write collection view code on cell class. And give collectionview delegate to cell because cell is super class of collection view. Check this screen shot
 [image]